# How to disable Postfix SPF from rejecting mail?

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail-server

I am having an issue with Postfix and SPF that I can't seem to figure out. I have installed SPF for Postfix using the guide on this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/SPF) (postfix-policyd-spf-perl).

However, I don't want Postfix or Mail::SPF to "reject" mail if it fails. All I want it to do is add the Authentication result to the emails header like it normally does. I have tried to find a config file for postfix-policyd-spf-perl but I can't seem to locate anything.

Below is an example of the rejection message:

```
mail.xxxxxx.com #<mail.xxxxxxxx.com #5.7.1 smtp; 550 5.7.1
<xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com>: Recipient address rejected: Please see 
http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=mfrom;id=xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com;ip=xxx.xx.xx.xxx;r=MAILER>
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, you cannot just disable spf partly, you either use it or you don't.

It's the owner of the SPF/TXT record that can choose to soft- or hardfail by using `~` or `-` in the dns record.

However, you could just disable spf so it won't be used by your postfix. Depending on your setup it's probably done by disabling / removing `check_policy_service unix:private/policy` from the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` in postfix `main.cf`

Comment: it's also possible to perlscript some function that checks the SPF record and adapts spamassassin score if you want.

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 16.04), the entry in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` was called `check_policy_service unix:private/spfcheck`